# Is there an "easy" way to migrate users on website database from MsSql authentication provider to MySql authentication provider?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server, authentication, migration

I have a website built on ASP.NET using the built-in authentication provider. I want to move from using Microsoft SQL Server to MySql.

I have managed to get the data copied over, but the MySql authentication provider uses an integer type ID field rather than the GUID type that the Microsoft SQL Server provider uses.

Is there an easy way (tool or script) to copy over the users and update the id all of the linked records? I can do it manually if necessary but I figured that someone might know a better way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrating users from SQL Server to MySQL will be a manual process. I am not aware of a script to do that.